# How to assign variable name and value to a dictionary as key value pair in python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to take a variable and the variable value and append them to a dictionary:

```
mydict = {}
myvar = 5
mydict[myvar] = myvar.value

>>> mydict
{myvar : 5}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what would the type of `myvar` in the expression `{myvar : 5}` be? (in your example `myvar` is just and `int`...) did you mean `mydict['myvar']`?

Comment: `mydict['myvar'] = myvar`

Comment: yes the idea is just to be able to use the name of the variable as a key and then the value could be an int or a float. thank you for your help

Comment: This is impossible for arbitrary variables. `myvar` is just a reference to a memory address whose content happens to be `5`. This reference has no idea that it is "called" `'myvar'`. **However**, you may be surprised if you do `print(locals())`

Comment: `print(dir())` will provide a similar output but as a list (containing only the names without the values)

Comment: So there is no way to isolate one specific variable name?

Comment: No, there is not. Not without a predefined knowledge about the name you are searching for.

Comment: Thank you DeepSpace for your kind help!!!

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in the comments, this is impossible for arbitrary variables (except of course hard-coding, for example `x = 5 ; {'x': x}`.

What *is* possible:

- Simply use `locals()` or `dir()` but you will get information you (probably) don't care about (such as current file path, imported modules, etc).
- Create a dictionary of specific variables while hard-coding their names:

  ```
  x = 1
  y = 2
  print({var_name: globals()[var_name] for var_name in ['x', 'y']})
  # {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
  ```
- Use a predefined knowledge about the variables you are searching for. For example, get the names of all defined `int` and `float`:

  ```
  a = 1
  b = 2
  c = 3.0
  print({var_name: var_value for var_name, var_value in globals().items() 
         if isinstance(var_value, (int, float))})
  # {'c': 3.0, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If using strings, to prevent existing globals strings from being added, use `startswith`

```
{var_name: var_value for var_name, var_value in globals().items() if isinstance(var_value, (str)) and not var_name.startswith("__")}
```